# SSMS - Add a column with data type datetime and default value for binding to current date and time

Tags: sql-server, ssms

Is it possible to add a column to an existing table  with data type "datetime" and then set the default value for binding to current date and time?

I am using SQL Server 2008.

Comment: Yes, you can use GetDate() as default value

Comment: Something like `ALTER TABLE tblX ADD colY DATETIME DEFAULT GETDATE()` and add `NOT NULL` if you want previous rows to be populated with current date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: See attached for an example. on how to do this]

See attached for an example. on how to do this